# Double click to Windows form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mouseevent

How can I detect, which mouse button have double clicked the form i.e. Left, Right or Middle?

**Updated:**
I am using .NET2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the last clicked button in **MouseUp** event and then check that in the double click event. Sample code:

```
MouseButtons _lastButtonUp = MouseButtons.None;

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _lastButtonUp = e.Button;
}

private void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (_lastButtonUp)
    {
        case System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left:
            MessageBox.Show("left double click");
            break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right:
            MessageBox.Show("right double click");
            break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle:
            MessageBox.Show("middle double click");
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [MouseDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx) and [MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.button%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [MouseButtons Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mousebuttons%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

MouseDoubleClick is one of the Form events.

Answer (score 1):

In Whatever_Click or DoubleClick event, you can check the MouseEventArgs e, which contains what key was pressed.

```
 private void Form1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
       Console.WriteLine("Left Mouse Button was clicked!");
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
       Console.WriteLine("Middle Mouse Button was clicked!");
 }
```

Other buttons include MouseButtons.Right, MouseButtons.Left

Comment: mouse double click do not have MouseEventArgs

Comment: Please recheck @Javed. I am currently using .NET Framework 3.5 and the MouseEventArgs is present :)

Answer (score 0):

in `form_MouseDoubleClick` event you can trace

```
void Form1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
       {
            // Do Operation
       }
 }
```